# Ubuntu Studio 19.10 Flickering Pixels

Tags: 19.10, amd-graphics

Good Day All

New user here hoping to jump over from Windows to Ubuntu.
I have performed a clean install of Ubuntu Studio 19.10 via DVD install, installation went without a hitch but when I get into the OS I have these strange flickering pixels that appear with any motion on screen (such as cursor movement, menus and typing). I switched screens and the problem still persisted and I hooked up my windows drive again and there aren't any problems.

I am currently running an AMD Ryzen 3 3200g with 16GB of 2933mhz memory.
Is there an issue with the drivers that I may need to update?
I'm currently living without a permanent internet connection but am able to update with an LTE modem if necessary.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Studio 19.10 uses Xfce as it's desktop manager. I have a Ryzen 5 3400G and I had to turn off the compositor in the system settings application, or install gnome or KDE plasma. AMD is late to the party with current drivers for the 19.10

Hope that helps